# jquery open tab via url or link

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, tabs

I have a standard tabbing section to divide content into separate tabs, similar to the jQuery tabs.
My problem, how can I open a specific tab via url (www.domain.com/content#tab2). In this case, it does not work by adding the tab thing to the url

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Default Action
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

        //On Click Event
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        });

    });


    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#welcome">welcome</a></li>
    <li><a href="#one">tab 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">tab 02</a></li>
   </ul>

    <section class="tab_container">
    <article id="welcome" class="tab_content"><p>content</p></article>
    <article id="one" class="tab_content"><p>content</p></article>
    <article id="two" class="tab_content"><p>content</p></article>
    </section>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using jQuery Tabs if you wish for the same functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in you `$(document).ready` function

```
    hash = window.location.hash;
    elements = $('a[href="' + hash + '"]');
    if (elements.length === 0) {
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
    } else {
        elements.click();
    }
```

Comment: i have tried out your solution but it still does not work on this http://www.akf-shop.de/modelle/hersteller-modell/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "selected" option of the jQueryTab to set the current tab, you will have to capture the URL option and set the tab on the page load event.

`$("#SimpleTab").tabs("option", "selected", 2);`

Refer the example at my blog: http://csharp-guide.blogspot.in/2012/07/aspnet-jquery-ui-tab-set-active-tab.html

Comment: You don't seem to have read the question at all. The user is using his own tabbing code; your example doesn't at all relate to what he's doing. You've also failed to disclose that this is your website.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have now on document ready

```
hash = window.location.hash;
elements = $('a[href="' + hash + '"]');
if (elements.length === 0) {
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
} else {
    elements.click();
}    

if($('.tab2').length>0){
   $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
   $("ul.tabNav li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
   $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

       //On Click Event
   var z = 100;
   $('ul.tabNav li a').each(function() {
      z--;
      $(this).css('z-index', z);
   });
   $("ul.tabNav li").click(function() {
      $("ul.tabNav li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
      $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
      $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
      var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
      $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
      return false;
    });
 }
```