# Accessing tabbed content from another page

Tags: jquery

I have small problem. I have a menu with three menu items and  pages

Home -
Products - products and it also contains tabbed content 1tab is "company info", 2nd tab is "contact us" 
Contact us - this is not a page but link to 2nd tab on the products page

I want know is there any possible way, when "contact us" is clicked directly go to 2nd tab on the products page

Comment: What do you mean with a tab? A browser tab? In that case, you'll have to resort to some fancy HTML5 JS API and see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). If these 'tabs' are made with some kind of library, please add which. If these 'tabs' are homebrew, please set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have 2 seperate pages. one of which contains the tabbed content. I want to access the tabbed content(tab has thee tabs I want to access the last tab) from the topmenu(which is same for all the pages).It is simple jquery tab. I dont think I can demonstrate it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are talking about some kind of jQuery tabs, in that case you can do something like

#### HTML link

```
<a href="index.php#contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

#### Jquery code:

```
// get the hash from the location
var tab = window.location.hash;
// get the <a> element with the href that matches the location hash,
// and fire a click event on it
$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a[href=' + tab + ']').click();
```

Note: The tab id should match the hash

#### Related:

- [jquery how to show specific tab with link from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419302/jquery-how-to-show-specific-tab-with-link-from-another-page?rq=1)
- [Using window.location.hash in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880669/using-window-location-hash-in-jquery)
- [jquery open tab via url or link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192572/jquery-open-tab-via-url-or-link)